# Sending a Soap Header with a WSDL Soap Request with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm extremely new to SOAP and I'm trying to implement a quick test client in PHP that consumes a ASP.NET web service. The web service relies on a Soap Header that contains authorization parameters.

Is it possible to send the auth header along with a soap request when using WSDL?

My code:

## php

```
$service = new SoapClient("http://localhost:16840/CTI.ConfigStack.WS/ATeamService.asmx?WSDL");
$service->AddPendingUsers($users, 3); // Example
```

## webservice

```
[SoapHeader("AuthorisationHeader")]
[WebMethod]
public void AddPendingUsers(List<PendingUser> users, int templateUserId)
{
    ateamService.AddPendingUsers(users, templateUserId, AuthorisationHeader.UserId);
}
```

How would the auth header be passed in this context? Or will I need to do a low lever __soapCall() to pass in the header? Also, am I invoking the correct soap call within PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to create a header and then add it to the client so it is sent for all subsequent requests. You will probably need to change the namespace parameter.

```
$service = new SoapClient("http://localhost:16840/CTI.ConfigStack.WS/ATeamService.asmx?WSDL");
//                        Namespace               Header Name          value   must-understand
$header = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'AuthorisationHeader', $value, false);
$service->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));   

$service->AddPendingUsers($users, 3); // Example
```

More information [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.construct.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$client = new SoapClient(PassportWebService);
$apiauth =array('userName'=>HeaderName,'password'=>HeaderPassport,'ip'=>$onlineip);

$authvalues = new SoapVar($apiauth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'ReqHeader',"SoapBaseNameSpace");
$header =  new SoapHeader("SoapBaseNameSpace","ReqHeader", $authvalues, true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```