# passing multiple WSDL header variables to SOAP server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am using SOAP web services for the first time and i am having a problem in calling the SOAP server. I searched through WSDL SOAP request not i am not able to solve my problem. This is the snippet of my WSDL

```
<s:complexType name="VerHeader">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HD1" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HD2" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HD3" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    <s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
```

I have to send username, password and some ID in these HD1, HD2 and HD3 variables. I have also tried these links [Passing a PHP array in a SOAP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338573/passing-a-php-array-in-a-soap-call) and [Sending a Soap Header with a WSDL Soap Request with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589228/sending-a-soap-header-with-a-wsdl-soap-request-with-php)

Here is what i have tried but not working, every time i run my code it send failure message, can you figure it out what's wrong with my code or my logic?

```
$soap = new SoapClient("http://example.com/verifyrecord.asmx?WSDL");
$header = array('HD1'=>'000000023','HD2'=>'val2','HD3'=>'val2');
$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'VerHeader ', $header);

$soap->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

Comment: what is the failure message  you are getting

Comment: failure message is the custom failure message sent by the SOAP server. I am afraid that the array that i am passing might not be in the correct structure and it keep me sending failure message due to authentication. i just want to verify that the array is in correct structure according to my SOAP server header

Comment: @utta: The [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589228/sending-a-soap-header-with-a-wsdl-soap-request-with-php) should answer you that. Also sometimes those who run a webservice don't do it right as well, so contact their technical support as well when you've verifified you do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. I solved it not by using php functions but creating an xml file manually and sending it to the soap server. I've posted an example of my answer so that it might be helpful to others. Thanks all for the help.

```
// the xml to send
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <VerHeader xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
      <HD1>000000000117</HD1>
      <HD1>user</HD1>
      <HD1>password</HD1>
    </VerHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:VerifyTransaction xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/">
        <m:object1>45344</m:object1>
        <m:object2>5545437</m:object2>
    </m:VerifyTransaction>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
// build your http request
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => "Content-type: text/xml\r\n",
'validateRequest'=>false,
'content' => $xml,
'timeout' => 10,
),
));

// send it
echo $xmlstring = file_get_contents('http://example.com/VerifyThis/VerifyThis.asmx?wsdl', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this

new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'VerHeader ', $header);

be

new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/verifyrecord', 'VerHeader ', $header);

Comment: how abt "http://example.com/verifyrecord.asmx?WSDL"making this as "http://example.com/verifyrecord.asmx"

Comment: that will not work as well coz if you remove WSDL then it will not call the soap service

Comment: new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'VerHeader ', $header); can you change it to new SoapHeader('http://example.com/', 'VerHeader ', $header); as your SoapClient is against SoapClient("http://example.com/verifyrecord.asmx?WSDL");

Answer (score 0):

try like this i did used this for my uk mail api .. and it worked

```
<?php 

 $LoginWebRequest = new stdClass();
 $LoginWebRequest->Username = 'xxx cant show here xxx';
$LoginWebRequest->Password = 'xxx cant show here xxx';

//echo "<pre>";  print_r($LoginWebRequest); "</pre>"; exit;

$Login = new stdClass();
$Login->loginWebRequest = $LoginWebRequest;

 //echo "<pre>";  print_r($Login); "</pre>"; exit; 

 $soapClient = new SoapClient('https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl');
 $LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);

  ?>
```